# How to inline input and button inside table cell in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been trying to figure out how I can get input field and a button on the same line inside a table cell without stretching the column too much.

This is what I want to be inline:

```
<td>
   <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control"id="measured_value" name="measured_value" placeholder="Measured value">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" onclick="add_measurement();">Submit</button>
</td>
```

This is what I get:

[image: screenshot]

I have also tried using divs with col-lg-8 and col-lg-4 it did inline them but that in turn stretched the column a lot. It made the column like 1.5 times wider and I am trying to make the table compact.

Comment: can you try to remove all class from input and button. I think then after you can get better idea from it. remove one by one.

Comment: It seems removing form-control from the input gets them on the same line, but of course it loses the other visual effects it had too.

Comment: from that any one class is affecte to submit button. you have to check that which class is that. and after that play with that class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that **form-control** is the reason why it wouldn't inline. So I ended up removing **form-control** and adding this for the borders which came with the form-control.

```
.input-sm{
   border: 1px solid #CCC;
   border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Easiest way is to make them float. For example:

**CSS**:

```
.input_class{
float:left;
}
.btn{
float:left;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't change anything. They remain exactly the same.

Comment: Sorry @Firze, but the code you have provided is data insufficient. Please provide, bit more HTML and CSS Codes.